# How to use round_sum in Python?

Tags: python, math

In pycharm the outputs are coming back correctly but when I execute in [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p179960) some test cases provide the wrong answer.

> round_sum(16, 17, 18) → 60
>
> round_sum(12, 13, 14) → 30

My code:

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
  return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)

def round10(num):
  n=int(len(str(num))-1)
  if num >=5 and num <=10:
    return 10
  elif num >=1 and num <5:
    return 0
  elif num%10**n >= 5:
    return int(math.ceil(num / (10 ** n)) * 10)
  else:
    return int(math.floor(num / (10 ** n)) * 10)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: What in the world is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to round to 10, because this is not what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
       def round_sum(a, b, c):

         return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)

       def round10(nums):

         return (((nums+5)/10)*10)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The following was my solution. It returns the **correct** values

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
  a = round(a,-1)
  b = round(b,-1)
  c = round(c,-1)

  return a+b+c
```

I guess people can get a general idea with this solution

[CodingBat-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ssLV.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
def round(num):
  modulo = num%10
  
  if modulo < 5:
      return num - modulo

  return num + (10 - modulo)


def round_sum(a,b,c):
  return round(a) + round(b) + round(c)
```

You design a helper function to avoid code repetition because otherwise you would have to code the same check three times (for each variable a,b,c).
In this helper function you basically check upon the modulo of the variable divided by 10. Let's see an example:

```
round(18)
18%10 => modulo = 8
modulo is not < 5
=> return 18 + (10 - 8) = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ! It is working perfectly .

Also I am attach the screenshot of the output .

---

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
  return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)

def round10(num):
    n=num%10
    if(n>=5):
        return (num-n+10)
    else:
        return (num-n)


print(round_sum(16, 17, 18))
print(round_sum(12, 13, 14))
print(round_sum(25, 32, 102))
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Your `round10` method does not work. You can use Python built-in `round` instead.

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
    return round(a, -1) + round(b, -1) + round(c, -1)
```

The second argument of `round` is the digit precision. Set to `-1` it will round to ten.

```
round_sum(16, 17, 18) # 60
round_sum(12, 13, 14) # 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full Question:

For this problem, we'll round an int value up to the next multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is 5 or more, so 15 rounds up to 20. Alternately, round down to the previous multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is less than 5, so 12 rounds down to 10. Given 3 ints, a b c, return the sum of their rounded values. To avoid code repetition, write a separate helper "def round10(num):" and call it 3 times. Write the helper entirely below and at the same indent level as round_sum().

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
    return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)


def round10(n):
    if n % 10 >= 5:
        return n + 10 - (n % 10)
    return n - (n % 10)


print(round_sum(12, 13, 14))  # → 30
print(round_sum(16, 17, 18))  # → 60
print(round_sum(6, 4, 4))  # → 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works perfectly fine it uses round function of python but if you're asking this question specifically as an answer to the coding bat problem then this code will not work there maybe because in that question you are asked to use a different helping function.

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
    sum = 0
    for i in [a,b,c]:
        num = 10*round(i/10)
        sum += num
return int(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
 def round_sum(a, b, c):

    return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)

  def round10(num):

   if num % 10 < 5:
        return num - (num % 10)
    
   return num + (10 - num % 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me;

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
  return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c) 
  
def round10(num):
  mode = num%10
  if mode >= 5:
    return num + (10 - mode)
  else:
    return num - mode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
   return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)

def round10(num):
if num % 10 < 5:
    return num - (num % 10)
else:
    return num + (10 - num % 10)

#Let's say num is 13
#if 13 % 10 < 5
#      3    < 5
#   return 13 - (13%10)
#   return 13 - 3
#   return 10

#Let's say num is 17
#if 17 % 10 < 5
#      7    < 5  ---> IS Not True
#else:
#return 17 + (10 - 17 % 10)
#return 17 + (10 -    7   )
#return 17 + 3
#return 20
```

Please try this code and comment below if you need more questions relating to it. It works perfectly on CodingBat as well. I have also attached note as an example using Hashtag sign #.